# Formula to copy the data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, excel-2016

**BACKGROUND**

I have 1 workbook, with 2 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2)

- Sheet1 has lots of data in column B.
- Sheet2 is blank currently, but will contain a formula.

---

**PROBLEM #1** - I would like to display the column data Sheet1!B1:B on Sheet2!A1:A**

Using Google Sheets, I can achieve this using: `=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B2:B)` but this formula does not work with Excel.

In Excel, I tried `{=Sheet1!B2:B}` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but it only returns the first cell.

---

**PROBLEM #2** - I would like to display the column data Sheet1!B1:B on Sheet2!A1:A with conditions.**

Using Google Sheets, I can achieve this using: `=QUERY(Sheet1!B2:B,"WHERE B is not null AND B = TRUE")` but this formula does not work with Excel either.

Comment: In `Excel-2016` you have put formula in `A1` cell of sheet2 then must drag down formula manually. But in `Excel-365` you can dynamically pull data from sheet1.

Comment: Darn! Thanks for clearing that up.